# Appending field from sub-query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a rather complex query that orders the results based on a sub-query. This works fine. The query is below.

```
 SELECT enrollments.*, users.*
 FROM enrollments
 INNER JOIN users
 ON enrollments.user_id = users.id
 WHERE enrollments.preview = FALSE
 ORDER BY (
   SELECT COUNT(progress_tracker)
   FROM progress_tracker
   WHERE progress_tracker.enrollment_id = enrollments.id
   AND progress_tracker.completed = TRUE
 )
```

Here I'm selecting the fields from the User and Enrollment table. I ideally want one more field in the sql results. This field represents the results from the ORDER BY sql:

```
SELECT COUNT(progress_tracker)
FROM progress_tracker
WHERE progress_tracker.enrollment_id = enrollments.id
AND progress_tracker.completed = TRUE
```

Is it possible to create a field from this query and append it to the results for each row? The name of the row would be appropriately termed as `enrollment_progress_tracker_completed_count`. If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the subquery to the `select` and then use it for ordering:

```
SELECT e.*, u.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM progress_tracker pt
        WHERE pt.enrollment_id = e.id AND pt.completed = TRUE
       ) as newcol
FROM enrollments e INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON e.user_id = u.id
WHERE e.preview = FALSE
ORDER BY newcol;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a temporary table

```
with tempCounts as(
SELECT enrollment_id, COUNT(progress_tracker) as countValue
FROM progress_tracker
WHERE progress_tracker.completed = TRUE
group by enrollment_id)

SELECT enrollments.*, users.*,tempCounts.countValue
 FROM enrollments, users.*,tempCounts 
 INNER JOIN users
 ON enrollments.user_id = users.id
 WHERE enrollments.preview = FALSE
and enrollments.id  =  tempCounts.enrollment_id
 ORDER BY tempCounts.countValue
```